# Spring bean config using static method from another bean with grails DSL

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-dsl

On Grails 2.3.7, a service exposes several decorator methods:

```
class CacheManager {
  static ReadOnlyCache getReadOnlyCache(name)
  static ReadWriteCache getReadWriteCache(name)
}
```

I want to configure services with these decorator methods, something like this:

```
beans = {
  cacheManager(CacheManager){ ... }

  pdfProcessor(PDFProcessor){
    documentCache = ref('cacheManager').getReadOnlyCache('docscache')
  }
  isbnValidator(ISBNValidator){
    cache = ref('cacheManager').getReadWriteCache('simplecache')
  }
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

### UPDATE

Thanks to Ian's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350643/791406), I got this generic solution working:

```
@Singleton
class CacheManager {
  static ReadOnlyCache getReadOnlyCache(name)
  static ReadWriteCache getReadWriteCache(name)
}

beans = {
  cacheManager(CacheManager){ bean ->
    bean.factoryMethod = 'getInstance'

  cacheDecorator(MethodInvokingFactoryBean) { bean ->
    bean.dependsOn = ['cacheManager']
    targetClass = CacheManager
    targetMethod = 'getInstance'      
  }

  pdfProcessor(PDFProcessor){
    documentCache = "#{cacheDecorator.getReadOnlyCache('docscache')}"
  }
  isbnValidator(ISBNValidator){
    cache = "#{cacheDecorator.getReadWriteCache('simplecache')}"
  }
```

Configure `cacheDecorator` as `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`, which returns singleton `cacheManager`, to safely invoke its methods.

Comment: If `getROCache` and `getRWCache` are declared static then you don't need to declare `cacheManager` as a bean, just call the static methods directly within the DSL.

Comment: Won't work, `cacheManager` requires its own spring config, and invoking any of its static methods before its initialized returns null, which is expected; is my approach the only alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to ensure the cacheManager is properly set up before invoking the getter methods then you could do that purely at the configuration level with something like

```
cacheManager(CacheManager) { ... }

pdfDocumentCache(MethodInvokingFactoryBean) { bean ->
  bean.dependsOn = ['cacheManager']
  targetClass = CacheManager
  targetMethod = 'getROCache'
  arguments = ['somecache']
}

pdfProcessor(PDFProcessor) {
  documentCache = pdfDocumentCache
}
```

The `dependsOn` should ensure the static `getROCache` method is not called until the `cacheManager` bean has been initialized.

Comment: Very nice, Ian! Made it more generic with `targetMethod = getInstance`, for calling any method without creating a new `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`